# Intellij Idea JPA console cannot run due '[3D000] No database selected'

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a project with JPA module that correctly recognizes all entities.
[image: JPA Console and Persistence tool]

Datasource is correctly set and it work well with autocomplete. I have not persistence.xml because I am using annotations.

I'm working a lot with @Query (native=false) on the repositories (extends CrudRepository) so using the JPA console it a really fast way to test queries.
But when I try to run queries there I am getting:

```
[3D000] No database selected
```

I cannot use the USE reserved word there. So I am wondering what may be missing on my configuration.

Comment: What is the Database? Check the data source settings: try to specify default database there or select it in [Data Source's **Schemas** tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#schemasAndTablesTab). Also try to set the schema in [Database Console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-console.html) for the data source. Do not forget to re-connect the JPA console after this. Does it help?

Comment: Hi @Andrey, I have checked it and all Datasources are set. When I run a script on a SQL console it works right, although sometime I must use 'Use db_name'. But since USE command is not available for JPQL console I getting that error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also struggled with this and found the solution.

When creating a datasource in IDEA, you can choose to which database you want to connect within that source. When left empty, no database is selected and you'll get the "[3D000] No database selected" error in the JPQL-console.

Instead, create a datasource *with* default database:
[image: add datasource]

Now, assign this datasource in the Persistence tool window (e.g. View | Tool Windows | Persistence) to your persistence unit:

[image: assign datasource]

And:

[image: assign datasource]

Now, you should be ready to go!

[image]